# Second UIWindow does not get any touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I have a second window I create to show a custom notification in my app:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window2;
```

And that's how I make it appear:

```
self.window2 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_BOUNDS.size.width, 50)];
self.window2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.window2.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
self.window2.rootViewController = custonViewController;
[self.window2 makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The problem is that no touch event inside custonViewController works.
I tried everything, even subclass `UIWindow` and override the `(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. But it doesn't work either.

How can I make my appdeledate to know the window2 has been touched/tapped?
Any ideas?

Comment: You make the window size small and off of the screen. Why do you expect touches to work?

Comment: NO I DON'T. IT APPEARS INSIDE THE SCREEN, i just typed -50 by mistake.. i just corrected it..

Comment: Please stop YELLING. You still have a problem that your window's height is only 50 points tall. Is that really all you want? That barely covers the status bar.

Comment: Yes, that's all i want. And it's plenty enough space for a Touch/Tap event to be captured. And it's over everything.
This is exactly what Whatsapp does as well and many other tech companies.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found out what happened.
I was animating the UIWindow to appear and disappear automatically, in a sequence of animations after the completion from the previous one with delay set with some seconds.
It locked any touch events during the whole sequence of animations.
So i separated the animations and put it in async threads, so it would receive touches normally.
bye!